# Prove that $\langle[a]\rangle=\langle[b]\rangle$ in $\mathbb Z_n$ iff $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

> Prove that $\langle[a]\rangle=\langle[b]\rangle$ in $\mathbb Z_n$ iff $\gcd(a,n)=\gcd(b,n)$.

Can anyone help?

Is it correct for => side?

Since $[a] = [b], a ≡ b \text{ mod } n$
by the definition of congruence modulo $n$
$$a − b = nk$$
for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. this implies
$$a = nk + b$$

if $x, y, q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $x = yq + r$, then $\gcd(x, y) = \gcd(y, r)$ taking $x = a$ and $y = n$.

Thus,
$$\gcd(a, n) = \gcd(n, b)$$

I have no idea for <= side
I stuck with this question for a long time :(

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reminder 
This is my first time to ask question in this platform

Comment: $\langle [a]\rangle=\langle[b]\rangle$ does not imply $[a]=[b]$.

Answer (score 1):

No.

One problem with your proof is that we cannot deduce $[a]=[b]$ from $\langle [a]\rangle=\langle [b]\rangle$. For example, in $(\Bbb Z_{10}, +_{10})$, we have that

$$\begin{align}
\langle[3]\rangle &=(\{[3], [6], [9], [2], [5], [8], [1], [4], [7]\}, +_{10}) \\
&=(\Bbb Z_{10}, +_{10}) \\
&=(\{[7], [4], [1], [8], [5], [2], [9], [6], [3]\}, +_{10}) \\
&=\langle [7]\rangle,
\end{align}$$

yet

$$\begin{align}
[3]&=\{ 3+10k\mid k\in\Bbb Z\} \\
&\neq\{ 7+10\ell\mid \ell\in\Bbb Z\}\quad(\text{because }3\neq 7+10\ell_0\text{ for any }\ell_0\in\Bbb Z) \\
&=[7].
\end{align}$$

---

**Hint:** We have $\langle [a]\rangle=\langle [b]\rangle$ iff both $[a]\in\langle [b]\rangle$ and $[b]\in\langle [a]\rangle$. Recall what a "power of $[x]$" means for $[x]\in\Bbb Z_n$. Use Bézout's Identity.